Sensor and motion system synchronization
Disclaimer: This is well outside of my field of knowledge. So please respond accordingly.
I am working on a project to measure hydrodynamic effects of a certain type of skin roughness in an open channel such as: flow depth, friction factors, velocities etc.. Up until now I have been making flow depth measurements using a point gauge situated at the top of the open channel, so given the channel length is 11m its a grueling task to make these measurements manually. So I have been thinking of attaching a range finder on a motorized carriage on the top of the open channel so that I can record flow depth measurements quickly and more frequently. Ideally I would like to have a flow depth profile with stream wise increments of 1mm. What do I need to do first? I know that I have to somehow synchronize the range finder and carriage motors so that when the range finder records a measurement I know to which stream wise location it belongs, but I don't know where to start my search. I was thinking this might be achievable using Arduino. Any suggestions or insights will be truly greatly appreciated.

What length of time is required to take a measurement? Could a slow, continuous carriage motion be used, taking measurements on-the-fly? Or must you stop to take a measurement, then move on?

Thank you for your response. I was thinking about a slow and continuous measurement.

Carriage motor shaft rotation sensors are a well-developed technology that is Arduino-friendly. You 'd have to decide if contact slip between motor drive and the surface it drives against (rail?) could manage 1mm resolution. If you use an 11m rail, a calibration ruler along its length might be possible. The calibration ruler might be optical or AC magnetic. Your question is rather broad - a more limited scope would be appreciated.

I totally agree with you my question is broad, because I'm unsure of the exact schematic of the system. I was hoping that somebody with experience would be able to help me narrow my problem down and support so as to get an efficient system. I was thinking about either a rack and pinon setup or rubber wheels, however, that depends on the financial resources available. In this regard, without taking much of your time, would you be able to briefly mention the pros and cons of either approach? As I don't have the experience to foresee what problems may arise due to either approach.

Using a carriage motor shaft rotation sensors is a brilliant suggestion. Would that work well regardless if the carriage traversed the channel using a rack/pinion or rubber wheels setup?

Rack and pinion is unlikely to slip whereas rubber (or any other material) might slip, thus creating error in your positioning. Another option is synchronous timing belt - rubber belt with teeth. Commonly used in motion systems.
